# How to set permission for run a program which is installed by root permission?

Tags: linux, permissions, fedora

I have installed the MyEclipse 10.1 via root permission and now when I want to run this program by my own user, it says that /opt/MyEclipse/MyEclipse\ 10/ is not writable! How can I solve this problem?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be enough for your user to own it. From a terminal, try the following:

```
chown -R $(whoami) /opt/MyEclipse
```

If you require other users to use that software, you need to let them run the MyEclipse executable as `root`. Per this forum entry by one of MyEclipse's support members:

> The only way to get that to work is to run MyEclipse as root -- because MyEclipse launches the server processes directly, so they launch with the original perms of the myeclipse process (in which case a normal user could never launch JBoss as root).

<sub>You *did* pay for that software – Try and use their [support forums](http://www.myeclipseide.com/index.php?module=PNphpBB2) in case of problems – that's what you paid for.</sub>

Comment: Is there any way to keep this folder for root user, I mean the root user remains the owner of this folder, but all users can work with this program?!

Comment: Can't you just start the program's executable with sudo privileges? That way it'll have write access.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend running random stuff as root/with `sudo`.  Seems like poor application design if it requires users to have write permission in its installation area, though.

Comment: @geekosaur Precisely what I was going to suggest next. Contact the vendor, maybe file a bug report.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall MyEclipse and re-install it as your own user - not to /opt.

As others have mentioned, the myeclipse forums are the best place to ask questions about myeclipse.